# One issues list where users can only see their assigned issues

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

Is it possible to have an issues list in sharepoint where users can only see their assigned issues (and not others)?

I don't think it's possible, since I believe views cannot be permission based.

Update:

My security restraint has been relaxed after review, so I won't have to worry about the saavy user manipulating the url ids, etc. I just don't want the user to be able to see a view called "All Issues" in the drop down list. Somehow hide this view by obscurity. Ideally, the user would only see a view called "My Issues".  However, I need an "All Issues" view for the contribute user to assign issues.  The users being assigned issues only need read-access to their issues.

I was thinking of adding a "master" issues list where the contribute user would maintain and have a sync routine (that I've already written) that would sync all the items to another issues list that only exposes the "Assigned To equal to [Me]" view (default) or can this be done easier by just having one list and somehow hide the "All" view from regulars users or something? I don't want the user clicking "All Site Content" and selecting the list to find the "All" view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the solution of copying a master list to another list with only the `Assigned To = [Me]` view exposed.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about true security or configuring a view?

If you're configuring a view, just set the filter for `Assigned To` equal to `[Me]`.

Comment: @ Kit, true security, so they won't be able to select any other views to see other user's issues

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'll need to break permissions on every list item. If you need to do this, you may want to consider writing a custom event receiver.

Comment: does WSS have item level permisson?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this OOTB features but you can use a Content Qwery Webpart. Check this post about [Content Query Web Part Alternative for WSS 3.0](http://vspug.com/erickraus/2007/09/19/content-query-web-part-alternative-for-wss-3-0/)  and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For true security, the problem is that a savvy user could always manually change the querystring of the DispForm.aspx URL to get into another list item. So I can think of a couple options:

1. Create a custom DispForm or a custom web part placed on the DispForm that calls [HandleAccessDenied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.handleaccessdenied.aspx) if the current user does not have Manage List permissions and is not the assigned user for the current List Item.
2. Add an [ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx) event receiver that will call [BreakRoleInheritance(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550474.aspx) and then grant Contribute access to the assigned user.

Comment: thanks, my security requirement has dropped a bit, see my update, but I will definitely keep these options in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Another option on the security route would be to use workflow to set permissions on the item to the person it is assigned to.  By doing it this way you can even allow people to re-assign the issue to others and then workflow can update the permissions.

Check out the custom SharePoint Designer Actions on CodePlex here: http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

I have also written a similar workflow action myself for list item secutiry that is a little more indepth than that of the codeplex one and mine also works with Forms Based Authentication - if you need this I may be able to arrange sending it over to you.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I might give that a try too and see if it meets my requirements, thx

Answer (score 0):

Views used in list web parts are not added to the default list views, so you could create a web part page or publishing page with a list web part that only has your [me] filtered list view, and lessen the exposure of the all items view.